# Format XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using java DOM to read an xml file, insert a new Element (tag) into it, and then store it bacc into the file. I would like to sort it by one of it's attributes, using XSL when saving the file. But i am a novice when it comes to XSL.

So, if i have xml like this :

```
<movie-theater>
    <catalog>
      <movie title="StarWars" director="George Lucas" madeIn="Holliwood"/>
      <movie title="LordOfTheRings" director="Peter Jackson" madeIn="New Zeland"/>
      <movie title="Batman" director="Tim Burton" madeIn="Holliwood"/>
    </catalog>
</movie-theater>
```

I would like to get a sorted xml like this :

```
<movie-theater>
    <catalog>
      <movie title="Batman" director="Tim Burton" madeIn="Holliwood"/>
      <movie title="LordOfTheRings" director="Peter Jackson" madeIn="New Zeland"/>
      <movie title="StarWars" director="George Lucas" madeIn="Holliwood"/>
    </catalog>
</movie-theater>
```

By applying an XSL template such as this :
(again, i am a novice whan it comes to xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/movie-theater/catalog">
        <xsl:for-each select="movie">
            <xsl:sort select="@title"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>              
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can you please help me figure it out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach to take here is to use the *identity transform* template as the default and only make an exception when applying templates to the `movie` elements by including a `sort` instruction:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="movie">
            <xsl:sort select="@title"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To do it the way you started, it would need to be something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <movie-theater>
        <catalog>
            <xsl:for-each select="movie-theater/catalog/movie">
                <xsl:sort select="@title"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>              
            </xsl:for-each>
        </catalog>
    </movie-theater>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: And now that you're more confortable with XSLT, your next step can be to throw away all that Java DOM code and use XSLT for the whole operation.